# Spring Boot 3 JpaSpecificationExecutor::FindBy(~) with Specification and Projection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-17, criteriabuilder

So I'm trying to use Specification with projection, this is a new feature on Spring Boot 3.

```
UserRepository repo;
Specification<User> spec;
Page<UserProjection> result = repo.findBy(spec, q -> q.as(UserProjection.class).page(pageable));
```

as viewed here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2499

But this implementation generates the same SQL as the regular findAll

```
UserRepository repo;
Specification<User> spec;
Page<User> result = repo.findAll(spec, pageable);
```

With the same SQL the use of projections is meaningless.
Is there anything missing on this implementation?

Comment: The reason it was not working is that my projection was not correctly designed, I had to rework the joins.

Comment: Please, could you show us your solution. We have got the same problem.

Comment: We did started it over and used criteria builder instead of specification. But I remember using Specification.toPredicate(Root, CriteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder) at some point to fix this.